# MAX7414 low-pass filter OS pin

Tags: filter

The datasheet of the [MAX7414](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7409-MAX7414.pdf) low-pass filter shows the OS pin connected to a voltage divider to set the output offset when the IC is used on a single rail supply. 
Can the OS pin be supplied by the REF1933 reference IC to set an output offset of 1.65V? 
The [REF1933](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ref1933.pdf) has a low output impedance, while the voltage divider shown in the schematic of the MAX7414 is formed from high value resistors. Will that affect the performance of the filter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any voltage reference since the OS pin will not load it (datasheet states \$10\mu A\$ leakage current). However, the voltage on the OS pin must be in range \$V_{COM}\pm0.1V\$. So, you cannot shift the output by \$1.65V\$.

Keep in mind that the output offset settings is used as correction. The output is biased due to common-mode input voltage of the \$V_{IN}\$ and \$V_{COM}\$ inputs. The differential input amplifier used on the input has 70dB common-mode rejection ratio. This allows bias reaching only milivolts on the output. Bias by \$1.65V\$ would be far out of this range.